# I left Windows 10 fast boot on

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I am using windows 10 and I decided to install ubuntu 14.04 (will update later)
from a thumb drive.I disabled secure boot from bios,but left fastboot on.Now I'm installing ubuntu.Can this cause any problem?

Note(If you didn't realize that):I am installing ubuntu **after** Windows 10.

Edit:It is booting straight into Windows.No grub nor something like that.What should I do?

Comment: Yes, that may cause problems. Fast boot (aka hybrid boot ) essentially works as partial hybernation . Hybernating one OS and going to the other may cause data loss. Read the answers on [this question](http://superuser.com/q/39532/418028) for example. However,  I've personally no experience with that, because I don't hibernate my laptop or PC, ever, only suspend. Other users may be more qualified to answer , so wait around a little

Comment: You'd better leave secure boot on, but disable fastboot. With fatboot Windows does not turn off and you will not be able to mount ntfs partitions.

Comment: It just booted to windows 10 so I can disable fast boot.I was scared that I might not boot into windows 10,but that didn't happen.So now I'll reboot again and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled fast boot in both amd64 bios and w/10. I also changed 'launch csm' in the bios from auto to enable. In the boot menu on the bios, I have to prioritise  ubuntu from a choice of o/s - when only the two exist - in the boot order section to get the usual grub menu after booting.  That gives me a choice of linux or w10 but where grub is located is yet to be found. It certainly isn't in the MBR as I have installed a further copy of 14.04 as a test bed for upgrade to 16 and that placed grub in the mbr - which is by-passed by the modified sequence. I have still to put that right so i can choose either of two linux partitions as well as w10.